# ActiveMQ cannot receive my message

Tags: tomcat7, activemq-classic

Hi i've added this WebListener class to my webproject

```
@WebListener
public class SelfSend implements ServletContextListener {

    private MessageProducer producer;
    private Connection sendconnection;
    private Connection receiveconnection;
    private Session sendsession;
    private Session receivesession;
    private MessageConsumer receiver;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        try {
            InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/ConnectionFactory");
            sendconnection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            receiveconnection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            sendsession = sendconnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            receivesession = receiveconnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            producer = sendsession.createProducer((Destination) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/queue/MyQueue"));
            receiver = receivesession.createConsumer((Destination) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/queue/MyQueue"));
            receiver.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(Message message) {
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE RECEIVED");

                }
            });
            TextMessage testMessage = sendsession.createTextMessage();
            testMessage.setStringProperty("from", "ki");
            producer.send(testMessage);
            System.out.println("MESSAGE SENT");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    }

}
```

But the message is never received.

When i put the reciver in a @WebServlet like this

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    try {
        InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/ConnectionFactory");
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        receiver = session.createConsumer((Destination) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/queue/MyQueue"));
        receiver.setMessageListener(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    mud = new MongoUserdata();
}
```

i recive the message, when i put it in both i receive only every second message with the Servlet-Receiver, the other messasge seems to be lost.

Can anyone explain theis odd behaviour to me?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example class you don't appear to be starting the receiver connection which would mean it will not dispatch any messages that are received.  It will however hold onto incoming messages in the consumer prefetch buffer leading to the every other message receive that you are experiencing.